# When to consider creating your own Ruby module in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

With a Ruby module, you can cluster together a bunch of methods that you might use in one place and then include them into a class so it's as if you had written them in that class.

**What kinds of practical uses are there for Ruby modules in a rails app?**

I would appreciate if someone could mention an example of where they've actually used a module of their own so I have a sense of what situations I should be thinking about creating them. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent question. Curious to see what answers you get.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can place them in the /lib directory and they'll be loaded with your Rails project.

For example, you can view this repo of mine of an old project: [lib directory of a Rails project](http://github.com/mwilliams/sports-charting/tree/06efac324f6284fa04b7a37ae25845eb4cec9194/lib)

So for example, I have the following module:

```
google_charts.rb

Module GCharts
  class GoogleCharts
    def some_method

    end
  end
end
```

And anywhere in my Rails app, I can access the methods.

So if I were to access it from a controller, I would simply do:

```
require 'google_charts'

GCharts::GoogleCharts.some_method
```

Comment: Thanks. The implementation details are good to know about. But I was thinking more along the lines of what types of functionality in a Rails app you would use a module for encapsulating.

Comment: Anything that doesn't belong in your controller or model :).  In other projects, we've had a utilities.rb that didn't really have a place within any controller/helper/model but were necessary.  So we tucked them away in the lib directory.  Also, other libraries that we write that don't need to be their own plugin.

Comment: How do you determine when something falls short of being a plugin but doesn't belong in the controller or model?

Comment: Maybe it's a temporary thing or something just so trivial that we don't want to go through the trouble of making it a full blown plugin.  At that point, it's really just a decision that won't really matter one way or another.  It's a matter of preference of you, as the developer and what's going to make you happy.

Comment: @mwilliams module shouldn't be capitalized in your code example.

Answer (score 18):

1) Any time I'm about to duplicate (or substantially duplicate) a piece of code:  "oh, i could just cut/paste into this other controller . . . "

2) Any time I write code that is very obviously going to be reused in the future.

3) Code of substantial size that has a specific purpose, where that purpose is fairly distinct from the main purpose of the controller/model.  This is somewhat related to (2), but sometimes code won't get reused but a module helps for organization.

Answer (score 7):

We use modules for functionality that isn't tied to ActiveRecord models and hasn't been abstracted into a plugin or gem.

A recent example from our production code base is a library for integrating with Campaign Monitor for email list management. The core of the system uses our user model, but the actual interaction with the extenrl service is abstracted through a module that lives in /lib.